# Rewrite Rule Block by User Agent and Referral Url Error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am getting error 500 in my logs when using the below Rewrite Rules to block by User Agent and Referral URL. I have tried removing the referral url block but still getting error 500 for the user agent block. The traffic that is not block work properly.  Just getting 500 for bots and refurl that are blocked.  Any idea why is it giving me 500 instead of 403 in the log?

```
# Block by REFURL
RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} sample\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Block by User Agent
RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot1 [NC,OR]    
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bot2 [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]

# BLOCK BLANK USER AGENTS
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^-?$
 RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Here is sample of one of the log. My server use cpanel so I pull this from the raw access log.  I only get error log when an IP has been block.  It doesn't show anything for the 500 errirs.

```
xx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [02/Sept/2014:21:54:25 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 500 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; BadBot/5.0; +http://badbot.com/robot/)"
```

Comment: check your Apache error.log and tell us what the error is?

Comment: I added the log in my question.

Comment: Actually this log is from access.log not from error.log. I need matching line from error.log

Comment: Error log didn't show anything for this.  Only thing I have from error log is when the blocked IP hits 403.  Not sure if this will help but I also used <Limit GET POST HEAD> to block IP addresses and those show up just find as 403 as I mentioned.

Comment: I won't be able to assist further until I see actual error text causing 500 in Apache error.log